# Horizontal scroll on top in Reports

Tags: sharepoint, reporting-services, ssrs-2012

How I can add in SSRS report additional horizontal scroll on top of report ?
Example: [Horizontal scroll on top](http://postimg.org/image/vykhb4c2f/)

I deploy reports to SharePoint

Comment: What kind of application are you displaying the report in? Web or desktop? asp.net / vb.net / winform / wpf/ ...?

Comment: In Web, Sharepoint Site.

Comment: I found how do it in html with javascript (http://suwala.eu/blog/2012/02/01/horizontal-scrollbar-top-and-bottom-element/)  But how deploy this to sharepoint ? is possible ?

Comment: Rdl doesnt support Javascript